# How prove this $a+b+c+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac})$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, schur-inequality

let $a,b,c>0$, show that
$$a+b+c+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac})$$

I know this 
$$a+b+c\ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$$
so 
$$\Longleftrightarrow 6\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac})$$
But this maybe not true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WLOG suppose that $a\geq b\geq c$.

First see that using weighted AG-inequality, we have:
$$
c+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\geq 4\sqrt c \sqrt[4]{ab} (*)
$$
Then we have:
$$
a+b+c+3\sqrt[3]{abc}- 2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac})=\\
(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2-4\sqrt{ab}+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\\
\geq (2\sqrt[4]{ab}-\sqrt{c})^2-4\sqrt{ab}+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\\
= c- 4\sqrt c \sqrt[4]{ab}+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\geq 0\\
$$
The last one is positive due to $(*)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=x^6$, $b=y^6$ and $c=z^6$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive numbers.

Hence, by Schur and AM-GM we obtain:
 $$a+b+c+3\sqrt[3]{abc}=\sum_{cyc}(x^6+x^2y^2z^2)\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^4y^2+x^4z^2)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(x^4y^2+y^4x^2)\geq2\sum_{cyc}x^3y^3=2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}).$$
Done!